# NgRepeat is not updating from an updated array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an app that gets a collection of data (i.e. 400 objects) and stores it in an array. In my view I'm creating a kind of infinite scroll, that basically when the page loads, it insert 5 records. Then I have in the bottom a button labeled *more* that goes to the data array and slices it for the array that is being used in the *ngRepeat* directive.

At first it starts to work, but than keeps failing. The function is being fired but the list with *ngRepeat* isn't updating.

My controller example is:

```
 function ActivityController($uibModal,$http,$q, UserService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.activity = [];
        vm.activityData = [];
        vm.maxItems = 5;
        vm.getMoreData = getMoreData;
        function getMoreData(){
            vm.activityData = vm.activity.slice(0, vm.activityData.length + 5);
        }

        UserService.getUserActivity()
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.activity = response.data;
                    vm.activityData = vm.activity.slice(0, 5);
                });
    }
```

View:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="activity in activityCtrl.activityData | orderBy: 'date':false " class="list-group-item">
                    <p class="nm">
                        <i class="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <strong>@{{ activity.user }}</strong> @{{ activity.operation }} @{{ activity.type }}  @{{ activity.name }} no Gestor</p>
                    <small class="text-muted">@{{ activity.diff}}</small>
                </li>
            </ul>
                <button ng-click="activityCtrl.getMoreData()">more</button>
```

Comment: What comes if you `console.log(vm.activityData)` in the end of your `getMoreData()`. Does the `scope` get update but the changes do not reflect in the view ?

Comment: perhaps if you made an example (like [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrFv6OjaXwj33xoY578l?p=preview)) it would help illustrate the issue

Comment: Could you please share the data your dealing with ? I've create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eebrjno4/) but I can't reproduce the problem. Propably there's something wrong with the `orderBy` filter.

Comment: Why pass *false* to [**orderBy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), when that is the default?

Answer (score 3):

Try use `$scope.$evalAsync` function.

```
    function getMoreData(){
        $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
         vm.activityData = vm.activity.slice(0, vm.activityData.length + 5);
        })  
    }
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data =[{"name":"a","age":"25"},{"name":"b","age":"23"},{"name":"c","age":"21"},{"name":"d","age":"21"},{"name":"e","age":"22"}];
  
  $scope.data2 =[];
  $scope.updateData = function(){
    var d = {"name":"newA","age":"25"};
     $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
         $scope.data.push(d);
       })
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="updateData" ng-click="updateData()" />
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
         <td>{{d.name}}</td>
         <td>{{d.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wiping out your entire array. You should push the next elements into it.

```
function ActivityController($uibModal,$http,$q, UserService) {
    var vm = this;

    angular.extend(vm, {
        activity: [],
        activityData: [],
        maxItems: 5,
        getMoreData: function () {
            var sizeToGo = vm.activityData.length + maxItems;
            for (var i = vm.activityData.length; i < sizeToGo && i < vm.activity.length; ++i) {
                vm.activityData.push(vm.activity[i]);
            }
        },
        onInit: function () {
            UserService.getUserActivity()
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.activity = response.data;
                vm.activityData = vm.activity.slice(0, 5);
            });
        }
    });

    vm.onInit();
}
```

You should also add a `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="activity in activityCtrl.activityData track by $index | orderBy: 'date':false " class="list-group-item">
</li>
```

Comment: When i click in getMoreData function at the first click inserts all data, is not filling 5 records each time.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in my for loop condition. You can get the new `getMoreData()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but unfortanlly it is getting the same issue that i have, in a certain moment starts failing :S

Comment: Have you tried to add a `track by $index` in your ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is caused by re-assigning `vm.activityData` rather than updating it's contents.

```
function ActivityController($uibModal,$http,$q, UserService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.activity = [];
    vm.activityData = [];
    vm.maxItems = 5;
    vm.getMoreData = getMoreData;

    function getMoreData(){
        // add another 5 items
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(vm.activityData, vm.activity.slice(vm.activityData.length, 5));
        });
    }

    UserService.getUserActivity()
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.activity = response.data;
                // add the first 5 items
                Array.prototype.push.apply(vm.activityData, vm.activity.slice(0, 5));
            });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Wrapped the updating of `vm.activityData` with `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Its not updating in the ngRepeat, it keeps already the initial 5 records